# Tomcat as Windows service how to pass a Java property

Tags: java, service, tomcat8

We currently run the tomcat 8.5 as windows service. How is it possible to pass over a java property i.e. via -D parameter to the startup of the service?

- do we can pass over a parameter through the service properties dialogue "startup parameters" of the windows operating system (Service Manager). If yes what would be the syntax?
- do we need to hard code that property somewhere in the startup bat files of tomcat, if yes which ones?
- other possibilities i.e. system variable like CATALINA OPTS?

Thank you and regards
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First sure that you had ran `Service.bat install` then please run Tomcat7w (or Tomcat8w, Tomcat9w if you use another Tomcat version).

Select [image: Java in Opened windows] and add Java Properties in Java Options.

If you install service with another name, example `service.bat install TomcatApp` then please rename Tomcat7w to [image: **TomcatApp**w] before open.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the *Environment Variable Prerequisites* section of the `catalina.bat` script in Tomcat 8.5:

```
rem   JAVA_OPTS       (Optional) Java runtime options used when any command
rem                   is executed.
rem                   Include here and not in CATALINA_OPTS all options, that
rem                   should be used by Tomcat and also by the stop process,
rem                   the version command etc.
rem                   Most options should go into CATALINA_OPTS.
```

You should be able to set the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable with your custom `-D` parameters.